# Remove or compensate rotation angle for (ifc) model

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have integrated the forgeviewer in our application. We provide the function to compare two models. Now, some models have a rotation. If a model with a rotation is compared with one that does not have the same rotation, the models cannot be compared well.
[image: two models combined]

I would like to solve this problem. The only solution I can think of is to compensate the rotation for the viewer. Since each model has a different rotation, I would like to do this dynamically. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this.
I think something like this should be possible:

```js
  private static buildLoadOptions(
    bubbleNode: Autodesk.Viewing.BubbleNode,
    viewer: Viewer3D,
  ) {
    const visibleModels = viewer.getVisibleModels();
    const globalOffset = this.extractGlobalOffsetOrDefault(visibleModels);
    const displayUnit = this.extractDisplayUnit(visibleModels);
    // get the rotation
    const rotation = bubbleNode.searchByTag({ rotation });
    const mat = new Matrix4()
      // adjust it
      .makeRotationZ(-rotation);

    return {
      placementTransform: mat,
      globalOffset: globalOffset,
      sharedPropertyDbPath: bubbleNode.getViewableRootPath(),
      applyScaling: displayUnit,
    };
  }
```

Comment: The rotated model seems to have rotation values in the IfcDirection values of the IfcProject's IfcGeometricRepresentationContext. Could you check my suggestions in the `Don't want the IFC model rotated by the angle to true north` section here?: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/faq-and-tips-ifc-translation-model-derivative-api